# reading TCP as client via akka-stream

Tags: scala, sockets, tcp, akka, akka-stream

I'm new to akka-stream and attempting to use the library as a client to read (and only read) from a remote TCP server socket.

My attempts however fail as no incoming *ByteStrings* are being processed.

neither:

```
Source.empty[ByteString]
      .via(Tcp().outgoingConnection(address, port))
      .to(Sink.foreach(println(_))).run()
```

nor:

```
val connection = Tcp().outgoingConnection(address, port)
val sink = Flow[ByteString]
  .via(Framing.delimiter(
ByteString("\n"),
maximumFrameLength = 256,
allowTruncation = true))
  .map(_.utf8String)
  .to(Sink.foreach(println(_)))
connection.
  runWith(Source.empty, sink)
```

works.

What are the reasons for the flows not being run? All hints much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ViktorKlang mentioned, the empty `Source` on the client side is causing an issue where the flow essentially won't be run.  You can setup the pipeline to start receiving only by using a single empty `ByteString` `Source` instead of an empty one as the example below demonstrates:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val mater = ActorMaterializer()
val server = Tcp().bind("127.0.0.1", 2555)
server.runForeach{ conn =>
  Source.tick(1 second, 1 second, "foo")        
    .map(f => ByteString(f))
    .via(conn.flow)
    .to(Sink.ignore).run
}

val clientFlow = Tcp().outgoingConnection(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 2555))
clientFlow.runWith(Source(List(ByteString.empty)), Sink.foreach(bs => println("client received: " + bs.utf8String)))
```

If you do this, then you will start receiving data from the server every second in accordance with the tick source created on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for hinting about `Source` this helped indeed.

Comment: This did not work for me. My server produces infinite data, but your version gives up after a relatively small amount of time. The "Source.maybe[ByteString]" version from Richard Searle, though, works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

You need a Source that does not complete and does not generate any data, such as Source.maybe.
Note that the Promise it creates can then be used to terminate the flow.

```
Source.maybe[ByteString]
.via(Tcp().outgoingConnection(host, port))
.to(Sink.foreach(println(_))).run()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not being run because it never has any data to process: You have an empty stream so it terminates immediately.

Comment: Thanks for this hint! In the discussed case this looked as a sane way to implement - essentially I am not intending to send anything there. The solution proposed by @cmbaxter enforces a dummy element to get the stream running.